# I got this error with "await" in C# Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, asynchronous, windows-phone, async-await

I'm building a music app and I want to access an SD card. I get an error with `await` though.

Comment: no pictures... please...

Comment: Did you try to do what the error explicitly is telling you?

Comment: I apologise, My English is not good so I just explain by picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the method `async` in order to use the `await` keyword within it:

`private async void ListView_ContainerContentChanging(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you used `await` method, your method must also be an `async`. You must change your method definition:

```
private async Task [MethodName] ([parameters])
```

Comment: It's an event handler. Event handlers can't be `async Task`, they can only be `async void`. It's the one time it's appropriate to use `async void` over `async Task`.